# Problems with bootable... anything

Tags: ubuntu, usb, boot

recently i have made several bootable USB drives with a variety of linux distributions ranging from Ubuntu to Backtrack using the Unetbootin installer. lately however, the devices created stopped working altogether, and will not boot. i tried using a DVD instead, but it would not boot, and instead showed a black screen saying that it could not find the kernel, and when i typed it in, the computer said the boot kernel is invalid. i don't see how this could be possible, having downloaded the OS from the websites with no tampering whatsoever. When i use a USB drive, the machine just flashes "invalid operating system" or something of the sort (goes away too fast to see). What is going on here?

Comment: What other USB devices are connected? Have you looked at the settings in the BIOS?

Comment: everything is fine in the BIOS, and no other USB devices are connected

Comment: So, is this a problem with the USB drives or with the computer they're used on?

Comment: They don't boot in your PC or in any PC?

Comment: @AndréNeves i do not know, only having one elderly pc laptop, the rest of my computers are mac

Comment: Don't you think that the problem may be that something changed with your computer, not with your dozens of sticks?

Comment: i suspected that, but what possibly could have changed?

Comment: Have you got a system installed on that notebook? Or you're just booting from removables?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete, definite answer, but I know that Unetbootin wasn't able to create valid Live-USB installs for Ubuntu recently (I think around 11.04).  That might be continuing into 12.04, and perhaps it could be a more far-reaching bug.

How did you make the DVDs?  You might want to try burning them again at a lower speed; sometimes you can get unreported errors during creation.

It might also be a good idea to go to pendrivelinux.com (or use the built-in USB creators of many OSes) or some other site to get an alternative USB-creator.

Maybe you could try updating your BIOS if nothing else seems to work.

UPDATE:  Ridiculous that I seem to have missed this, but you have tried MD5 checking, right?  The most likely thing is that your files are corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have changed HDD mode from SATA mode or IDE mode to AHCI ..

This is most common mistake people do .

If not set bios to its defaults and retry.