# Virtual Machine problems

Tags: virtual-machine

I recently tried using backtrack 5 in a virtual machine (host is Mac OSX) after my bootable USBs stopped working (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/382037/problems-with-bootable-anything)). However, this too shows the message:

[image]

and when I type in the name of the kernel, it shows:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the host machine platform what virtualization software is this, where are you loading the OS image from etc?

Comment: i downloaded the OS image from the Backtrack website, and it was loaded to the VM from my desktop

Comment: AT that prompt just hit enter, do not type anything. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16B2P7DiQhw